# AOP Ninject Stop Intercepted Method From Being Called

Tags: c#, ninject, aop, interception, ninject-interception

I'm using Ninject and AOP to do some caching.  I have a Attribute that I can apply to any method in my repository and on BeforeInvoke it will return my cached Object if there is one and AfterInvoke create a cached object.  This all works great but I can't figure out how to stop initial method from being called, ie if there is a cached object the return that instead of calling a the intyercepted method.  My interceptor is here:

```
public class CacheInterceptor : SimpleInterceptor
{
    protected override void BeforeInvoke(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Type returnType = invocation.Request.Method.ReturnType;
        string cacheKey = CacheKeyBuilder.GetCacheKey(invocation, serializer);
        object cachedValue = cache.Get(cacheKey);
        if (cachedValue == null)
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        else
        {
            object returnValue = serializer.Deserialize(returnType, cachedValue);
            invocation.ReturnValue = returnValue;
            returnedCachedResult = true;
        }
     }
}
```

Even though in the else statement I am clearly not saying to call the invoked Method 'invocation.Proceed();' it still invokes it.  How do I tell ninject to just return with the invocation.ReturnValue  ?

Comment: Are you sure that your interceptor is being called? Are you able to step through it in the debugger?

Comment: yes the interceptor is being called, I can see the invocation.ReturnValue = returnValue; being setbut then it calls the method as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `SimpleInterceptor` in this case because that is meant as base class for the most common scenario where you want to do an action before or after the actual method call. Also you are not allowed to call `Proceed` Instead implement the `IInterceptor` interface and put your code into the `Intercept` method.

But probably we should extend `SimpleInterceptor` in a future version so that you can prevent that the actual method is called:

```
public abstract class SimpleInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private bool proceedInvocation = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Intercepts the specified invocation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="invocation">The invocation to intercept.</param>
    public void Intercept( IInvocation invocation )
    {
        BeforeInvoke( invocation );
        if (proceedInvocation)
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            AfterInvoke( invocation );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When called in BeforeInvoke then the invokation in not proceeded anymore.
    /// Or in other words the decorated method and AfterInvoke won't be called anymore.
    /// Make sure you have assigned the return value in case it is not void.
    /// </summary>
    protected void DontProceedInvokation()
    {
        this.proceedInvocation = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes some action before the invocation proceeds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="invocation">The invocation that is being intercepted.</param>
    protected virtual void BeforeInvoke( IInvocation invocation )
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes some action after the invocation proceeds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="invocation">The invocation that is being intercepted.</param>
    protected virtual void AfterInvoke( IInvocation invocation )
    {
    }
}
```